# Product informations template

Tags: magento-1.8, product, catalogsearch

I would like what template is invoked to display product information when you click on result list of catalog search.

```
Search in catalog by keyword -> list of results > click on a product
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In your case template file path** :

`app/design/frontend/[your_theme]/default/catalog/product/view.phtml`

You can find **which template file** is rendered using below steps

`System > Configuration > Developer (under Advanced) > Debug (then change store scope to Website View in top left) > Template Path Hints` (**change to Yes**), and then refresh front end page.

OR

Use free extension called **Easy Template Path Hints** with which you can just turn on the template path hints both for frontend and backend easily using query strings.

You will get to know the file from which it is called.